# Create button to add another group of form inputs in front end of website

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a form that will be used to help book vehicle rentals for a company.  Right now, I only have a group of fields showing for information about one vehicle.  I would like to have a button or link a user can click on to "add another vehicle," which would add the group of fields related to vehicle and rental information (pick up date, drop of date, vehicle type, etc.).

I found some code that is supposed to do what I want, but for some reason I can't get it working.  I have a feeling it's something simple, but I've been staring at it for so long I can't figure out what it is.

At the moment, I just need the "Add Another Vehicle" link to add the content I specify (right now just the "Testing" paragraph).  I don't have to worry about sending the form data yet, as that will have to be handled through Modx. (And, I need to go one step at a time!)

Here is a link to the page I'm working on: http://www.cedrent.com.au/contact-form-test.html

The relevant script is just before the closing head tag, and it should be appending to the "vehicleFields" div located in the middle of the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can group and clone the related fields using the `clone()` method

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Just wrap the `$("#vehicleFields")` with another div so you can deep clone the `$("#vehicleFields")` and append it to the wrapper.

A simplified sample as below
http://jsfiddle.net/Quincy/ZA56n/1/

But keep in mind that if you do this, you have to first remove the `id` attributes of the elements in `$("#vehicleFields")` first. Because `id` should be unique across a single html and using `clone()` would also copy the id, which violates this rule.

```
$(function(){

$("#addVehicle").click(function() {
    $("#vehicleFieldsWrapper .vehicleFields").clone().appendTo($("#vehicleFieldsWrapper "));

});

  });
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Though when I implement it on my test page, it no longer seems to work.  I tried removing the other scripts I have on the page to see if something was interfering, but I still didn't have any luck.  Am I missing something?  The example you gave is working perfectly on JSFiddle.

Comment: You should wrap the script in the page ready event. Please read edited answer.

Comment: Oh, duh, I really should have caught that.  Thanks, it works out great!